# Is there a way create a wsdl from pom data?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, pom.xml, ear

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a wsdl from data available in a pom.xml file.

Basically, every project we build uses a pom that contains developer information, project information, version information -- all kinds of things that'd be handy to have available in some format within a web app.

If the app builds an ear, I'd like to dump all of this data into a page that would be standard in every build, so that no matter what environment (dev, qa, ust, srt, prod, etc) the app is in, you could hit a known, standard URL and get all the info you would need.

Has anyone implemented something like this? Or could someone point me at a possible means of doing so?

Comment: Would it work if you created a web service that returned the pom file?  I think you'll have to set this up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have never done this as extensively as you describe, but I do like to make some of the (POM) project information available in the runtime environment. Obviously it helps with issue tracking if you know the version number that was built, and I like to keep track of that in just *one* place: the POM.

I see three useful strategies off the bet:

- Write a Maven plugin that just traverses through the Maven model that it has access to and persist all in a file and format of your liking (I've just come up with this one, although I've written a good amount of custom plugins)
- Define a properties file within your classpath environment that is updated with the desired values at build time, using [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), and access the properties file on runtime (I've used this method a lot)
- Add additional `manifestEntries` to your archive's `MANIFEST.MF` (e.g. using the `war` plugin, `jar` plugin, whichever is appropriate) and access the manifest file on runtime, e.g. `getResourceAsStream`, `Manifest.getMainAttributes()`, et cetera (I've used this method; even though it's a little cumbersome I like that I'm putting project metadata in the manifest, which seems very appropriate)